# String with Turkish character to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, locale

on ubuntu:

```
> s = 'kasım' # ı -> 'i' without dot, lowercase letter, turkish.
> print s
> 'kas\xc4\xb1m'
> unicode(s, 'utf-8')
```

works just fine.

on windows:

```
> s = 'kasım' # ı -> 'i' without dot, lowercase letter, turkish.
> print s
> 'kas\x8dm'
> unicode(s, 'utf-8')
```

throws an unicodedecode error;

- 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte  0xfd in position 3: invalid start byte*

before that, locales are set in code like the code below:

```
 if platform is windows:
         locale_to_set = 'turkish'
 elif platform is linux:
          locale_to_set = 'tr_TR.utf-8'

 locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale_to_set)
```

What is the part i did wrong or missed? any idea will be appreciated.

note:
i am getting that 'Kasım' word (which means november) from datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(....) and user can change the language according to preference.

Comment: That error looks wrong. There is no position 6 on that string.

Comment: pardon me, i simplified string while asking question.

Comment: The fact that `s` contains different bytes on Windows than on Unix should suggest that `s` is not, in fact, a UTF8-encoded string on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to depend on the input encoding of your system, because those can differ from system to system, as you discovered. For this reason, it is better to avoid non-ASCII characters in your source code and use symbolic names. For example:

```
name = u'kas\u0131m'
```

If your string is coming from elsewhere in the system, such as from a localized `strftime` function, you will want to use the proper locale when decoding it into Unicode:

```
ignore, encoding = locale.getlocale()
name = unicode(s, encoding)
```

Comment: i am getting that 'Kasım' word (which means november) from datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(....) and user can change the language according to preference.

Comment: @AlperTokgöz Maybe you should explain that in the question. My answer is attempting to respond to the question as posed...

Comment: i added an extra explanation.

Comment: @AlperTokgöz I've now updated the answer to cover the word coming from `strftime`.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking python to convert a series of bytes into a unicode string, and saying that the bytes are utf-8 encoded. But your own code otutput shows that under windows the series of bytes isn't in utf-8, which is why you get the error.

Without commenting on the decision to set different locales depending on the operating system, to get that code to work, you'll need to specify a different character set when running under windows in the line

```
unicode(s, 'utf-8')
```

-- whatever character set is set by setting the locale to 'turkish' under Windows.